# Почему не отрабатывает функция записи в бд?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, дорогие форумчане.
 Никак не могу понять, почему не отрабатывает функция записи в бд.

```
function set_substrate ($id_1,$name,$substrate_path){
    $sql1 = 'INSERT INTO `substrate`(`id`,`id_tickets`,`name`,`substrate_path`)';
    $stmt1 =  $this->link->prepare($sql1 . " VALUES (0,?,?,?);");
    $stmt1->bind_param("iss", $id_1, $name, $substrate_path);
    $stmt1->execute();
}
```

Проблема в переменной $id_1.
Если вручную ее задаю `$id_1=100;`, то функция отрабатывает и запись в БД идет.

```
$id_1=$id_tickets[0][1];
//$id_1=100;
var_dump ($id_1); //показывает что переменная типа int
$variable = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$db_ftp->set_substrate($id_1, $variable ,$targetFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Значение значения не имеет, что пришло, то и запишется. Если поле нуллабле и пришел нул, а иначе API будет вопить о недопустимости, и надо просто посмотреть лог ошибок или прерывание направить в нужное русло. Если Insert ничего не оставил и при этом никто не возникает - это ненормальное API. Так не бывает.

Comment: Не совсем понял, о чем вы.  

$id_tickets[0][1]=11; в данном случае.

Var_dump самого массива $id_tickets
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(22) [1]=> int(11) } } 

В БД поле, в которое записывается эта переменная имеет тип INT. 
 
Менял его на VarChar, тоже не помогло.

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка.

Если делаю приведение типов

$id_1=intval($id_tickets[0][1]);

запрос выполняется, но $id_1 записывается в БД как 0, однако var_dump показывает int(11).

Comment: Вы не можете передать ничего, кроме "типа" string. Никаких int, long, double, real, decimal, etc. Все ваши типы превращаются в строку самоочевидным способом конкатенации безразлично в каком месте. Числа от текстов отделяются кавычками, причем числа можно точно так же кавычить, db engine уже разберется, а вот тексты не кавычить нельзя. Поэтому если в запросе нет ошибок, то запишется то, что было получено. Не записаться не может. Если не записалось, значит есть ошибка, ее надо искать.
_____
Есть теория, что тип поля у вас - текстовый, а вы думаете, что числовой. Проверьте.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4z5i6q 
Сама таблица.
http://prntscr.com/4z5id5

Comment: Это неоперабельно. Вы все проверяете не там и не тогда. По анамнезу можно выдвинуть диагноз: у вас пишется NULL в поле, которое не нулабле. Я вам с первого раза написал об этом, вы попробовали прочитать ошибку записи? Если запись не прошла - возникла ошибка. Все, что надо, - вывести ее и почитать. Вы не выводите и не читаете, а ходите в трех соснах.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array( "переменные в правильной порядке");
$stmnt1->execute($data);
```

Не могу понять, зачем Вам бинд данных, если вы их не приводите к какому-либо типу данных (ну, может быть, я что-то недопонимаю).